# Custom taxonomy thumnbails for custom post type on category page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I need display the custom taxonomy thumnbail and name on category page. I have this code :

```
<h1><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php

    $taxonomy = 'kategorie_goralskie';
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 
    'meta_value', 'order' => 'DESC') ); // Get all top level terms of a 
    taxonomy

    if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
   ?>

   <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
    </div>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

It shows only name of child (its ok) I must show thumnail too. How i can do it ? I tried in many ways
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAKMw.png)

In front-page.php everything is ok, i see taxonomy parent - just look : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cYEt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `the_post_thumbnail` function somewhere in your loop to display thumbnail. you can pass the size of the thumbnail you whant in function parameter.

See the detail of this function here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/

Comment: I don't belive what I did. I have custom taxonomy with thumbnails but in single product i had not the thumnbails ... maybe i needed a rest. Thanks for answer !

Comment: If it for a custom post type you need to specify you want to use thumbnail in your post type declaration. you need to specify the "supports" argument when you call register_post_type function. see edulcorate example on the documentation page https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type